# WMI Error : RPC Server is unavailable

Tags: wmi, remote-access

I have a PC, which have a public IP *192.public.1.10* and local IP *192.168.Local.10*.
I wish to use WMI Explorer to connect to this PC from a different network, which is connected through VPN.

Now I can use WMI Explorer to connect to this PC, from the same network using local IP & Public IP.

I can use WMI Explorer to connect to this PC, from a different network using **only** local IP. I want to WMI connect to it using public IP. Now I receive an exception "RPC server unavailable", while trying to connect it.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?